# I want to get the text of an html element and put it in a JavaScript variable

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following div:

```
<div id="mydiv">something</div>
```

I need to get the content of the div (mydiv) and put it into a JavaScript variable. How can i do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var content = document.getElementById("mydiv").innerHTML;
```